# How to migrate an existing table that has a column defined as XML schema to a new database with same definition

Tags: sql-server

I have an existing database that has a table which has a column defined as XML schema. How do I migrate/re-create this in a different database. I need to know the sequence of steps.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an SSIS package to take care of this for me.  To learn more about SSIS, visit:

[Video Tutorial illustrating how to copy one database to another.](https://youtu.be/JdR6WV4kh2Y)

This is a fairly common practice in the industry. There is alot of documentation on getting started using keywords like Visual Studio and SSIS.  You'll need Visual Studio and the SQL Server Data Tools installed.  Visual Studio offers a free community edition.

Comment: I did try using SSIS ..but it fails on the XML column 
CREATE TABLE SUBSCRIPTION 

[subscription_Lines] [xml](CONTENT [dbo].[SubscriptionLinesSchema]) NULL

Comment: Make sure the new table is already created, the columns are already defined, user has insert permission on database and then execute the SSIS package.  The SSIS package should be taking only the tuples from old db and inserting them into the new db. If that doesn't help.  Refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/extract-data-by-using-the-xml-source?view=sql-server-2017. If not that, Export XML data from old db and import it into new database.